# mvn archetype:generate Error building POM (may not be this project's POM)

Tags: maven-2, pom.xml

I am trying to create a jsf+spring+hibernate from a spring project. Below are the steps i have taken. I have been successful in creating projects in the past using the same method.
I have no idea where i am making the mistake.

Looking for all the hints, where i am going wrong.

NB: I have made the inputs and error messages as bold.

M:\SCHOLION\SPRING\maven>**mvn archetype:generate**

```
Choose a number:  (1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8/9/10/11/12/13/14/15/16/17/18/19/20/21/22/23/24/25/26/27/28/29/30/31/32/33/34/35/36/37/38/39/40/41/42/43/
**Define value for groupId: : com.unibz
Define value for artifactId: : springacltutorial
Define value for version:  1.0-SNAPSHOT: : 1.0
Define value for package: : springacltutorial
Confirm properties configuration:
groupId: com.unibz
artifactId: springacltutorial
version: 1.0
package: springacltutorial**
 Y: : y
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Using following parameters for creating OldArchetype: appfuse-basic-jsf:2.0
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Parameter: groupId, Value: com.unibz
[INFO] Parameter: packageName, Value: springacltutorial
[INFO] Parameter: package, Value: springacltutorial
[INFO] Parameter: artifactId, Value: springacltutorial
[INFO] Parameter: basedir, Value: M:\SCHOLION\SPRING\maven
[INFO] Parameter: version, Value: 1.0
 ********************* End of debug info from resources from generated POM ***********************
[INFO] OldArchetype created in dir: M:\SCHOLION\SPRING\maven\springacltutorial
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESSFUL
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2 minutes 1 second
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Jun 03 11:15:59 CEST 2009
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

M:\SCHOLION\SPRING\maven>cd springacltutorial

M:\SCHOLION\SPRING\maven\springacltutorial>dir
 Volume in drive M is Data
 Volume Serial Number is 76A4-1C35

 Directory of M:\SCHOLION\SPRING\maven\springacltutorial

03.06.09  11:15    <DIR>          .
03.06.09  11:15    <DIR>          ..
03.06.09  11:15            32.930 pom.xml
03.06.09  11:15               826 README.txt
03.06.09  11:15    <DIR>          src
               2 File(s)         33.756 bytes
               3 Dir(s)   8.521.940.992 bytes free

M:\SCHOLION\SPRING\maven\springacltutorial>**mvn compile**

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] **Error building POM (may not be this project's POM).**


Project ID: org.appfuse:maven-warpath-plugin

Reason: POM 'org.appfuse:maven-warpath-plugin' not found in repository: Unable to download the artifact from any repository

  org.appfuse:maven-warpath-plugin:pom:2.0-SNAPSHOT



[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1 second
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Jun 03 11:16:12 CEST 2009
[INFO] Final Memory: 1M/4M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: did OMax's answer fix your problem?

Answer (score 2):

Your generated project depends on org.appfuse:maven-warpath-plugin which you need to install or provide repository to fetch from first.

In central repo there is 2.0.2 latest version of this plugin:
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/appfuse/maven-warpath-plugin/

Try to specify this version explicitly in maven-warpath-plugin declaration if it is not there.